# Issues while upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

My computer crashed during the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 and since then I receive this message when I get to the command line.This is the command I used for the upgrade

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

How can I resolve this?

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Have you tried `--do-release-upgrade`? That is the preferred method. I know `-d` checks first, but I haven't executed one that way; maybe it ends up the same. As for your admin directory being locked... you should be able to restart to fix that. If you're feeling wild, try `pkill -KILL -u root` which will kill all root processes. Then you'll more than likely have to restart anyway, but I wouldn't delete the lock file..

Comment: I am using 16.04 and have had a few issues, too, but they are getting hammered out really quickly thanks to AskUbuntu. Just stick with it. It's a great release. Another thought is that if your package manager is open (GUI version, Synaptic, whatever you use), then that would lock your admin directory too. Check `ps` root processes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be frowned upon, but you could try deleting the lock file... then re-attempting the upgrade:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

After that, try opening Synaptic again.